# How to arrange divs after hiding other div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to achieve live result filter. i have three filters Good fit , bad fit and scheduled. When good fit is clicked it should show panels only with class good_fit_panel. Consider i have 5 panels.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
<div class = "panel good_fit_panel">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
<div class = "panel bad_fit_panel">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
<div class = "panel good_fit_panel">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
<div class = "panel bad_fit_panel">
</div>
</div>
```

These are my filter links.

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick = "javascript:filterGoodFit()"><B>GOOD FIT</B></a></li>                                                                
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick = "javascript:filterBadFit()"><B>BAD FIT</B></a></li>
```

my function to filter

```
<script>
    function filterGoodFit(){
       $(".good_fit_panel").show();
       $(".bad_fit_panel").fadeOut(500);
        }

    function filterBadFit(){
       $(".good_fit_panel").fadeOut(500);
       $(".bad_fit_panel").show();
        }
</script>
```

This does what i want , it hide other panels apart from the search query. But the problem here is. It hides and leaves the empty space. Since i am new to JS i don't know how to go about this and rearrange them.

Comment: The issue comes from the fact your elements are in divs that have a `width`. You could hide this parent instead of the element itself: `$('.bad_fit_panel).parent().fadeOut(500);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @pistou in the comments, you should really show and hide the parent divs of the panel divs as they are the ones that determine the amount of space taken. Thus, replace all:

```
.show();
.fadeOut();
```

With, respectively:

```
.parent().show();
.parent().fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need `slideUp(), slideDown(), slideToggle()`